# TFS query to get WorkItems with specific children

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

Our workflow defines that we place tasks with tags like "TEST" or "DEV" inside stories in order to track what type of work remains for that story.
I'm trying to write a query that would filter out stories that have only TEST tasks still not completed.
For example:

Story A has 2 tasks: TEST and DEV. TEST's state is to-do. DEV's state is In-Progress.

Story B has 2 tasks: TEST and DEV. TEST's state is to-do. DEV's state is completed.

Story C has 1 task: TEST. TEST's state is to-do.

Story D has 1 task: TEST. TEST's state is completed.

Story E has 1 task: DEV. DEV's state is to-do.

The query I am looking for would return stories B and C only.

Is this possible with vanilla TFS? Are there extensions that allow for more complex queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use **WIQL** which resembles Transact-SQL to achieve such complex queries. It' a extending work-item tracking.

> To explore the details of the work item query language, create queries
>   by using Team Explorer, and then save them as .wiql files. Rename the
>   files to use the .xml extension, and open them in Visual Studio. Look
>   for the **wiql** element to see how each query is expressed in the work
>   item query language.

More details please refer the document from MSDN: [Query for Bugs, Tasks, and Other Work Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306(v=vs.120).aspx)